# How to handle login failed error in NextAuth.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth.js for Next.js authentication. Login works fine, but the page is still reloading on wrong credentials. It doesn't show any error. I need to handle error to show some kind of toast message.

```
signIn("credentials", {
      ...values,
      redirect: false,
    })
      .then(async () => {
        await router.push("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        toast("Credentials do not match!", { type: "error" });
      });
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When passing [`redirect: false`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option) to its options, `signIn` will return a `Promise` that [only in email and credentials provider types](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/641d917175026ec974d1d255064b2591db0c56e6/packages/next-auth/src/react/index.tsx#L227-L233) resolves to an object with the following format.

```js
{
    error: string | undefined // Error code based on the type of error
    status: number // HTTP status code
    ok: boolean // `true` if the signin was successful
    url: string | null // `null` if there was an error, otherwise URL to redirected to
}
```

You have to handle any errors inside the `then` block, as it won't throw an error.

```js
signIn("credentials", { ...values, redirect: false })
    .then(({ ok, error }) => {
        if (ok) {
            router.push("/dashboard");
        } else {
            console.log(error)
            toast("Credentials do not match!", { type: "error" });
        }
    })
```

Comment: `NextAuth v4.10.3` is not injecting the session on signIn success so the router.push('/dashboard') will be with `session=null`. To fix that, do a `window.location.replace('/dashboard')` which will trigger a full refresh. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. More details here https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/1264

Comment: @GabrielLinassi saved my day. This problem still exist in `v4.21.1`. `router.push` followed by `router.reload` did NOT solve the problem. `window.location.replace` does.

Comment: This issue is already fixed on `v4.24.3`

Comment: How to handle the error when the `redirect: true` in a better way without redirecting this route `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Invalid%20credentials`??

Answer (score 1):

I use the method for next-auth error handling when I use `credentials`

```
const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (res?.ok) {
      console.log("res: ", res);
      signIn("credentials", {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("res: ", res);
      // TODO: Show error message with toast
    }
```