# Next-auth prevent redirecting when credentials are incorrect

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm building just an ordinary auth with next-auth Credentials. By default, Next-auth redirects to `api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin` if credentials are incorrect. I'm using modal form to sign in and it can be opened in any existing page, so if credentails are incorrect i want to push `?signin-error=CredentialsSignin` query to current url instead of redirecting. How can i do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to handle login failed error in NextAuth.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760933/1870780)? You have to use the `redirect: false` option.

Comment: @juliomalves yeap, `redirect: false` was what i were searching